# SAPI TTS Engine with multiple Voice

Tags: com, atl, sapi

I'd like to know if it's possible to handle multiple voices in a TTS Engine. Now I have an simple TTS engine which supports one voice. I'd like to extend it to support multiple voices in the same engine and switch to different voice internally within the engine. I want this just to avoid creating number of projects for each voice based on language or other parameters.

Thanks

Comment: So you're building an *engine*, not an application?

Comment: So when you say it supports one voice, does that mean you only have one SAPI voice, but you'd like other SAPI voices some that speak in other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.   Typically you would do this underneath your ISpObjectWithToken implementation (as described in the [TTS Engine Vendor Porting Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717037(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Sorry, I've completely forgotten that I posted here. I figured it out from the documentation that it can be handled. Thanks, I'll accept your answer.